# Open data downloaded from EMODnet website on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, bathymetry

I've downloaded some bathymetric data from EMODnet website. The file format is .emo

I know it's possible to open in QGIS, but doesn't work for me. Drag an drop, open raster, open mesh.. nothing works.
Any suggestion?

File - [https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8oosicd2s24plx/590_HR_Nazare.emo?dl=0[enter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8oosicd2s24plx/590_HR_Nazare.emo?dl=0%5Benter) link description here][1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8oosicd2s24plx/590_HR_Nazare.emo?dl=0)
[image: EMODnet Map Viewer]

Comment: How exactly did you download? Can you link to the data? There is a WFS available that can be used as-is in QGIS, see https://emodnet.ec.europa.eu/en/emodnet-web-service-documentation#data-download-services and https://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/ .

Comment: I've selected the high resolution bathymetric layer, clicked over and download option appear.

Comment: Where did you select the high res layer? Please make it easy for us to help you!

Comment: @til_b Hope you can download the file and try it..

Comment: to open .emo files you need to use software like SEANOE Sea scientific open data edition https://www.seanoe.org/data/00592/70460/ *QGIS will not open .emo directly (ESRI ASCII yes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bound to .emo files you could download the RGB GeoTiff or the ESRI ASCII.

Use ASCII if you want to use the bathymetrie to calculate, or want to apply your own color scale.

Use RGB GeoTiff if you only want to visualize the bathymetry.

Both versions will load without issue in QGIS 3.28.

Those are the download options in the EMODNET Map Viewer at https://emodnet.ec.europa.eu/geoviewer/ when you open the Catalogue tab, choose "EMODNet Bathymetry", then "DTM Tiles", tick the box called "Tile structure and download" and then click inside the map on the tile you need:

[image: download options]

ASCII with own color style applied:
[image: ASCII with own color scale]

Compared to the RGB GeoTiff:
[image: RGB GeoTiff]

Comment: Thank you so much. Brilliant. Solved

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted using the green checkmark on the left, below the answer score